# Will files copied to the Document folder of an extension be backup by default on iPhone?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-keyboard-extension

I am writing a keyboard extension for iOS 8. A sqlite database is copied from the bundle to the Document folder when the keyboard is started for the first time (not previous copy of the file exists):

```
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"work.sqlite3"];
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" 
                                                       ofType: @"sqlite3"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundlePath 
                                        toPath:dbPath error:nil];
```

In case the user restores the backup of this iPhone to a new iPhone in the future, will the `work.sqlite3` file be restored in the new iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a file to the bundle folder of your application

Answer (score 0):

in place of

```
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Use

```
func getTheFilePath() -> String
    {
        var url = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.groupBundleID") as NSURL?
        var path = url?.absoluteString?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("work.sqlite3") as String?
        path = path!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file:", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

        return path!
    }
```